# Copy a list of files from a text document

Tags: windows, xcopy

I would like to copy a  list of files that I have stored in a text document into a folder.

I have been using this script

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Source
set dst_folder=C:\Destination
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO (
xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

This asks me if I would like to overwrite or skip duplicate files. Is there a way to copy the duplicate files but append a number after the filename like windows does? There may be several duplicates of a file in the list.